# Are there any good tutorials for ice4j?

Tags: java, networking

I have just started using ice4j as an ICE client. I am experimenting with it, and I want to create a simple chat application using it. The problem is, I can't seem to find any good tutorials on how to use ice4j, and the Javadoc I compiled from the source code doesn't seem to help either. I don't want to resort to having to read through all the source code, because that would be annoying. Is there anything that can help me learn ice4j?

Comment: Bit late to mark as off topic...

Comment: Heres a recent tutorial from a GSoC participant http://blog.sharedmemory.fr/en/2014/06/22/gsoc-2014-ice4j-tutorial/

Comment: Here is a recent article focused on Ice4J http://www.stellarbuild.com/blog/article/ice-stun-turn-a-simple-explanation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reading [tests](http://code.google.com/p/ice4j/source/browse/trunk/test/org/ice4j/), usually it's the best documentation, especially when there's nothing decent about a techlogy

Comment: The tests are somewhat limited, but they are useful to see the full gambit of protocols that can be used. Otherwise there is a recent article focused on simple ICE4J http://www.stellarbuild.com/blog/article/ice-stun-turn-a-simple-explanation